Auto-Complete Case Milestones
I am hoping someone could please help me with Auto-Complete Case milestones.
I have implemented a Class as well as a Trigger from this article
public class MilestoneUtils {
public static void completeMilestone(List<Id> caseIds, 
        String milestoneName, DateTime complDate) {  
List<CaseMilestone> cmsToUpdate = [select Id, completionDate
        from CaseMilestone cm
        where caseId in :caseIds and cm.MilestoneType.Name=:milestoneName 
        and completionDate = null limit 1];
if (cmsToUpdate.isEmpty() == false){
    for (CaseMilestone cm : cmsToUpdate){
        cm.completionDate = complDate;
        }
    update cmsToUpdate;
    }
}

}
trigger CompleteFirstResponseEmail on EmailMessage (after insert) {
if (UserInfo.getUserType() == 'Standard'){
    DateTime completionDate = System.now();
    Map<Id, String> emIds = new Map<Id, String>();
    for (EmailMessage em : Trigger.new){
        if(em.Incoming == false)
            emIds.put(em.ParentId, em.ToAddress);
    }
    if (emIds.isEmpty() == false){
        Set <Id> emCaseIds = new Set<Id>();
        emCaseIds = emIds.keySet();
            List<Case> caseList = [Select c.Id, c.ContactId, c.Contact.Email,
                c.OwnerId, c.Status,
                c.EntitlementId,
                c.SlaStartDate, c.SlaExitDate
                From Case c where c.Id IN :emCaseIds];
        if (caseList.isEmpty()==false){
                List<Id> updateCases = new List<Id>();
                for (Case caseObj:caseList) {
                    if ((emIds.get(caseObj.Id)==caseObj.Contact.Email)&&
                        ((caseObj.Status =='On Hold')||
                         (caseObj.Status =='In Progress')||
                        (caseObj.Status == 'New'))&&
                        (caseObj.EntitlementId != null)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaStartDate <= completionDate)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaStartDate != null)&&
                        (caseObj.SlaExitDate == null))
                            updateCases.add(caseObj.Id);
                }
                if(updateCases.isEmpty() == false)
                    milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(updateCases, 
                            'First Response', completionDate);
        }
    }
}        

}
Things were working fine until a couple of months ago where the case milestone would not auto-complete when an email was sent to a customer.
Starting my investigation I first looked to see if the entitlement ID was being linked to the case.
I ran this SOQL query in my sandbox dev console to make sure entitlements were being linked to cases. They definitely are...
SELECT Id, Subject, EntitlementId FROM Case WHERE EntitlementId != null
My Entitlement is active as well. Milestones are there... Not sure what else to look for, I did make sure that the user triggering the email is a 'Standard User' using this querySELECT Id, Username, UserType FROM User WHERE Id = 'ID_HERE'
I made sure that the trigger was meeting the required conditions which is if the case status is on hold or is new etc and it definitely is
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Hi, welcome to SFSE! Is this failing consistently, or only in some cases? The reason I ask if you mention that the Case meets the criteria of 'On Hold' or 'New', but the logic in the trigger is only for Cases in the New and In Progress statuses. In addition, if it started failing, do you have an idea of what changes may have been completed at that time? It might help to pinpoint any other causes.

Hi Callum! sorry that code snippet is from my production org, in my sandbox I do have the condition set up correct. Also it does it with every automatic email sent by email alerts/Flows. funnily enough if I send 2 emails (making sure that the "to address" matches the personContact email address) then it will auto-complete. Thank you for getting back to me on this
